# Editing crontab with c# on mono-project

Tags: c#, macos, mono, cron

I was wondering if anyone know if we can edit the cron tab file with c# on mac and linux. I was also wondering if i can schedule tasks with crontab on mac and linux. Will the task start by themself or we have to specify specific date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can write to the crontab just like you could any other file. You can also schedule tasks with crontab on mac and linux, and they will run by themselves.

check out

http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

or

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=102626

for a crontab 'quickstart' guide.

You are going to have to be careful so that the integrity of the crontab is maintained. (not overwritten, not badly formatted, etc)

Comment: No problem, please speak up if any problems :)